# My 11-month-old child is shaking arms and legs when excited. Should I be worried?

Tags: behavior, infant, motor-development

I kind of feel like this is "normal" but I am also worried that while I am in awww over her preciousness and loving her cute little moments that I may actually be watching her having some kind of neurological problem.

I have asked the doctor and they said she is "fine" but my experience with doctors tells me that they don't always know everything.

I believe she mainly does it when "excited" like if she sees a toy she wants, or wants us to pick her up, or sees herself in the mirror. Her arms and legs begin to tremor as if she has so much excitement built up and doesn't know how to exert it.

Could this be a sign of baby anxiety or some kind of neurological issue? Does your baby do this? How old? How long? Did you get it checked out? What did they say?

I love my little baby sooooooooooo much and I just want to make sure she is as her best.

Comment: Providing a follow-up since this questions has been so popular. My daughter is 4 yo now and has turned out great. She is still very easily excitable which is awesome on holidays and new experiences but she doesn't tremor and shake anymore.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of my daughters has seizures and neurologically-caused muscle tremors.  Trust me, they are very distinct from a baby's excited quivering.  Babies are still learning how to control their bodies.  Something like keeping your arm from shaking seems easy, but is actually quite complicated from a control systems point of view.  Especially if a doctor has signed off, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you, seizures were kinda on my mind though I thought maybe it was really minor versions. Thanks for the reassurance all is well, it definitely isn't as uncontrollable as a seizure.

Answer (score 5):

Babies do this. My 16-month old is no different. She has a little more motor control than your 11m/o probably does, but she still shakes, bounces, sways etc when she sees something she likes.

Your baby is just fine.

Comment: Comforting.. yeah i probably would be freaking out if she hit 16mo and was still doing it. Thank you for the heads up, its quite adorable I just didn't want it to be something bad while I'm melting over her lol.

Comment: Agreed, my 16-month old daughter also kicks like mad when she sees one of us or a cat or dog. So well done, you just made her happy! One tip is if you're holding her to keep her legs away from your groin area (or anything breakable) when she's likely to get excited. Painful lesson.

Comment: @Tony it's normal to freak out

Answer (score 1):

Babies can do some odd movements and often if it's something new for them, they try it over and over again for awhile. At one point when my daughter was little and having trouble sleeping, she did this weird head shaking thing that looked very neurological but when we got her back to sleeping more, it went away (or maybe she just got tired of it). I seem to remember some other weird movements that also went away over time.

Something to think about is that if it were something bad neurologically, it would probably be involuntary, and she probably wouldn't do it consistently in response to stimuli if it were neurological. She might see something in your excited response that makes her keep doing it too.

It can definitely be hard to not worry about them with all the different things they do, but usually it goes away after a few weeks. :)